# C# Print long height form with printform component

Tags: c#

How can i print a form that has height more than screen height
(form has vertical scroll)?

Answer (score 1):

PrintForm only supports printing an *exact* copy of what you see on the screen.  The print-out will have a visible scrollbar as well.  And of course not show the controls that are scrolled out of view.

There's an excellent workaround for this, use the PrintDocument component.  The print-out will look *much* better as well, not the grainy bitmap you get out of PrintForm.  You do however have to write the code for the PrintPage event handler yourself.  A fair amount of code, but it isn't hard code.  Use PrintPreviewDialog so that you don't waste a tree debugging and fine-tuning your code.

Comment: <but it isn't hard code> Really? IMO, this is some of the most painful code to write for ordinary LOB apps. Usually better quality and easier to integrate reporting software such as the Microsoft Report Viewer control to do the printing.

Comment: @bin - to each his own I guess.  Tools like CR and RDLC were like Lisp to me.  Finish the project and promise to do that *never* again.  They are very unsuitable as a PrintForm replacement anyway.  Good for dumping a dbase query on paper, bad for form-based reports where nothing is ever repeated.  InfoPath would be a better fit.  Maybe.

Comment: Just printing the form is rarely a good solution. Invariably there are controls with scrollbars and nobody is ever happy with the truncated text being sent to the printer. So either you write more code that is in the actual form itself just so you can implement printing--with no help of any visual designer---or you go with a reporting tool. Sometimes you can get away with things if you do an old-fashioned style monospaced printout, but that might not go over very well either...